# How to send varying JSON data in Ajax post request

Tags: json, jquery

How can I send data in JSON format to an AJAX POST request.
My data consists of a JAVA person object with many attributes like name,dob,address,phone etc,
a list of Suppliers(supplier name, number) to this person, another list of helpers (helper name, number).
How do I combine all the data into a JSON object and send it in jQuery.post(url, data) ?

Comment: Build your data object just before you send the data

Comment: Do I just have to build it manually? var mydata = {person: jack, dob:1980-09-9, address: address} and so on? I am looking for an easier way to do this, if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a complex JSON object and submit that to the server.

```
var employees = { "accounting" : [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                                { "firstName" : "John",  // First element
                                  "lastName"  : "Doe",
                                  "age"       : 23 },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "age"       : 32 }
                              ], // End "accounting" array.                                  
              "sales"       : [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                                { "firstName" : "Sally", // First Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Green",
                                  "age"       : 27 },

                                { "firstName" : "Jim",   // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Galley",
                                  "age"       : 41 }
                              ] // End "sales" Array.
            } // End Employees
```

More info here: [JSON Examples](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29)

Answer (score -1):

Try JSON API ...

```
var person = JSON.stringify(
[{
     name:"dob johnson",
     address:"somewhere over the rainbow",
     phone:"+357 99798342"
   },{
     name:"john Doe",
     address:"4th barrel street",
     phone:"+357 927124442"
   }]
);
person = JSON.stringify(person);
```

Then send it to the server

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: {json:encodeURIComponent(person)},
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Server side then

```
// Decode ... $_POST['json']
jsonString = urldecode($_POST['json']);
```

Comment: I only have one "person" and more than one "supplier" and "helper". I need to combine all that info and send it to the server.

Comment: @Sapphire: So, just add those to the object.  What's the problem you are having?

Comment: so something like var postObject =[{person},{supplier1},{supplier2},{helper1},{helper2}]; ? (where person, supplier1,supplier2 are defined as shown here)

Comment: that's true, put any other entity in ... while the syntax is valid

Comment: sorry I said AJAX, but I need to open a new window with the specified url when I send the request.